# How to make Ajax request through NodeJS to an endpoint

Tags: ajax, node.js, q

I am using NodeJS. One of my function (lets call it funcOne) receives some input which I pass to another function (lets call it funcTwo) which produces some output.

Before I pass the input to funcTwo I need to make an Ajax call to an endpoint passing the input and then I must pass the output produced by the AJAX call to funcTwo. funcTwo should be called only when the AJAX call is successful.

How can I achieve this in NodeJS. I wonder if [Q Library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) can be utilized in this case

Answer (score 16):

Using [request](https://github.com/request/request)

```
function funcOne(input) { 
  var request = require('request');
  request.post(someUrl, {json: true, body: input}, function(err, res, body) {
      if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
          funcTwo(body, function(err, output) {
              console.log(err, output);
          });
      }
  });
}

function funcTwo(input, callback) {
    // process input
    callback(null, input);
}
```

Edit: Since request is now deprecated you can find alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143)

You can also use the built-in fetch API that comes with latest versions of nodejs(18+). See below for an example.

```
async function funcOne(input) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(someUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(input),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const body = await response.json();
      funcTwo(body, (err, output) => {
        console.log(err, output);
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle errors here
    console.error(err);
  }
}

function funcTwo(input, callback) {
  // process input
  callback(null, input);
}
```

Comment: request is now depreciated! :-(

Answer (score 6):

Since request is deprecated. I recommend working with axios.

`npm install axios@0.16.2`

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.url);
    console.log(response.data.explanation);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Using the standard http library to make requests will require more effort to parse/get data. For someone who was used to making AJAX request purely in Java/JavaScript I found axios to be easy to pick up.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html